# How to calculate horizontal distance between two lines

Tags: python

I have two sets of points A and B. Both A and B have the same x-values, it is only the y-values that differ.  As an example, consider the x-values to be:

```
[ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16,
   17, 18, 19]
```

For A the given y-values are:

```
[ 4,  1,  2,  7,  8,  8,  6, 11,  7, 10, 11, 15, 14, 14, 13, 17, 17,
   21, 22, 20]
```

For B the given y-values are:

```
 [ 3,  0,  1,  6,  3,  6,  9, 11,  8,  8, 11, 15, 14, 15, 17, 14, 18,
   17, 18, 20]
```

Straight lines are drawn between successive points in both A and B.

For each x-value (0 to 19 in this example), I want to know the distance in a straight horizontal line between the line from A and the line from B, always going to the right.  This picture gives an example where I have drawn the horizontal lines for x = 0, 1, 2, 3 .

[image]

For some points, for example at x = 6, there is no intersection with a horizontal going to the right of the line A point (6, 6). In this case the code can just report False or -1.

How can this be implemented?

Comment: Hi! Can you show us what you've tried so far? StackOverflow isn't a code writing service.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `zip` to get pairs of points in the series, and find the intersection using the formula `(y2-y1)/(x2-x1)=constant` for any pair of points on a straight line.

(Edit: thanks to another answer here I noticed that we also have to deal with horizontal line segments, which will otherwise cause a division by zero error.)

```
def find_horizontal_intersection(y, points):
    """ Return the x coordinate at which the straight line segments linking a series
        of points first intersect the horizontal line y=y

        Returns None if there is no intersection.
    """
    for (x1, y1), (x2, y2) in zip(points, points[1:]):
        if y1 == y2:   # if the segment is itself horizontal
            if y == y1:
                return x1
        elif y1 <= y <= y2 or y2 <= y <= y1: # Check the horizontal intersects this segment at all
            return (x2-x1) * (y-y1) / (y2-y1) + x1
    
A = [ 4,  1,  2,  7,  8,  8,  6, 11,  7, 10, 11, 15, 14, 14, 13, 17, 17, 21, 22, 20]
B = [ 3,  0,  1,  6,  3,  6,  9, 11,  8,  8, 11, 15, 14, 15, 17, 14, 18, 17, 18, 20]        
b = list(enumerate(B)) # b is a list of coords [(0, 3), (1, 0), (2, 1)...]

for x, y in enumerate(A):
    bx = find_horizontal_intersection(y, b[x:])
    if bx is None:
        print("B does not intersect y=", y)
    else:
        print("B intersects y=", y, "at x=", bx, "; distance=", bx-x)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the itertools recipe `pairwise` to create pairs of y-coordinates which you can use to generate sloped lines to test for intersection with a horizontal line. For example, the first pair would be `(3, 0)`, then `(0, 1)`, then `(1, 6)`, and so on.

Using one of the [line-intersection formulas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line%E2%80%93line_intersection#Given_two_points_on_each_line) on wikipedia, I was able to achieve the following:

[image]

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

a = [4, 1, 2, 7, 8, 8, 6, 11, 7, 10, 11, 15, 14, 14, 13, 17, 17, 21, 22, 20]
b = [3, 0, 1, 6, 3, 6, 9, 11, 8, 8, 11, 15, 14, 15, 17, 14, 18, 17, 18, 20]

def pairwise(iterable):
    from itertools import tee

    a, b = tee(iterable)
    _ = next(b, None)
    yield from zip(a, b)


intersections = []

for x1, y1 in enumerate(a):
    x2 = len(b)
    y2 = y1
    for x3, (y3, y4) in enumerate(pairwise(b)):
        x4 = x3 + 1

        try:
            t = ((x1 - x3) * (y3 - y4) - (y1 - y3) * (x3 - x4)) / ((x1 - x2) * (y3 - y4) - (y1 - y2) * (x3 - x4))
            u = ((x2 - x1) * (y1 - y3) - (y2 - y1) * (x1 - x3)) / ((x1 - x2) * (y3 - y4) - (y1 - y2) * (x3 - x4))
        except ZeroDivisionError:
            continue

        if 0 <= t <= 1.0 and 0 <= u <= 1.0:
            px, py = x1 + t * (x2 - x1), y1 + t * (y2 - y1)
            intersections.append((x1, px, py))
            break


plt.plot(range(len(a)), a, color="blue")
plt.plot(range(len(b)), b, color="orange")
for i, x, y in intersections:
    xs = [i, x]
    ys = [a[i], y]
    plt.plot(xs, ys, "r--")
    plt.plot(x, y, "r+")
plt.show()
```

That being said, this doesn't actually give you the distance, it just gets the points of intersection and plots them. However, getting the distance is trivial now - it's simply the difference between the x-component of the intersection point, and the x-component of the start of the horizontal line.

I'm not a fan of the whole "appending-in-a-loop" approach. A prettier solution would use a generator that yields intersection points, which you could then use to populate a list.

Comment: Thank you. Your pictures are great too. I will accept the other answer just because it explicitly gives the distances.